# Any way of using fully qualified table name with CREATE TABLE

Tags: mysql, create-table

When I use `CREATE TABLE tbl_name` I can only specify a table in database I currently use.
Is there any way to `CREATE TABLE` `tbl_name` in `database1` without a prior `USE database1`?

Comment: `The table name can be specified as db_name.tbl_name to create the table in a specific database.`. See [14.1.18 CREATE TABLE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```sql
mysql> CREATE DATABASE `test_1`;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE DATABASE `test_2`;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT DATABASE();
+------------+
| DATABASE() |
+------------+
| NULL       |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE `test_1`.`table_1` (`column_1` BOOL);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE `test_2`.`table_2` (`column_1` BOOL);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> USE `test_1`;
Database changed

mysql> SHOW TABLES;
+------------------+
| Tables_in_test_1 |
+------------------+
| table_1          |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> USE `test_2`;
Database changed

mysql> SHOW TABLES;
+------------------+
| Tables_in_test_2 |
+------------------+
| table_2          |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```